# Как изменить иконку приложения в фоне android?

Tags: android

я недавно в Android разработке и столкнулся с трудностью. После создания небольшого приложения не получается изменить иконку запущенного приложения в фоне. Она остается стандартной. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. [image: фоновая иконка приложения][image: иконка приложения]

AndroidManifest.xml
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

`

Comment: Вы пробовали очистить список запущенных приложений? Операционная система кэширует значки программ

Comment: Да, удалял весь кэш, но без результата. Телефон Xiaomi redmi 4x, android 7.

Comment: и в манифесте все верно указали?

Comment: покажите манифест

Comment: По моему достаточно удалить программу с телефона и поставить заново

Comment: @Романыч, добавил в тему. Все изображения в папке mipmap заменены.

Comment: @KosWarm, приложение несколько раз собирал заново и удалял несколько раз. Все равно отображается значок Android. Возможно дело в моем телефоне...

Comment: У вас указаны 2 разные иконки в манифесте.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в манифесте указаны 2 разные иконки.
В том числе

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round
```

И

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher
```

В данном конкретном случае она и отображается 
Можно round icon удалить для начала.
А основная иконка должна быть той , которая отмечена как ic_launcher, я надеюсь) она по сути и будет отображаться. Если нет просто замените путь на нужный. Например

```
android:icon="@mipmap/my_icon
```

И все будет работать как нужно